# Why converting result of multiplication of float to int fails?

Tags: python, php

I have come with a problem with programming language.

```php
//php
$a = (int) (10.20 * 100);
echo $a; 
// expected output: 1020
// output: 1019
```

```py
# python
int(10.20 * 100)
# expected output: 1020
# output: 1019
```

Comment: Short answer: round the result to the nearest integer.